# Getting build errors while running "nx build app-name"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, nrwl-nx, build-error, react-tsx

I recently had an accidental update of **@types/react** package to version **18.2.43** and **@types/react-dom** package to version **18.2.7** which started causing build errors in working code.

This is the build error I am getting after running the command

```
error TS2345: Argument of type 'Element' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReactNode'.
  Property 'children' is missing in type 'Element' but required in type 'ReactPortal

  29 |
  30 | root.render(
> 31 |   <StrictMode>
     |   ^
  32 |     <BrowserRouter>
  33 |       <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
  34 |         <GlobalStateProvider>
```

I was previously using **@types/react** version **18.2.4** and **@types/react-dom** version **18.2.6**. With this version I had no problem in building the app.

**Note: I am using nx workspace monorepo architecture for my application.**

File in which the error is occuring

```
import { StrictMode } from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { GlobalStateProvider } from '@apollo-e/global';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';
import 'react-loading-skeleton/dist/skeleton.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
import 'sweetalert2/src/sweetalert2.scss';
import 'simplebar-react/dist/simplebar.min.css';
import './index.css';
import { ToastContainer } from 'react-toastify';
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from '@tanstack/react-query';
import App from './app/app';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement);

const queryClient = new QueryClient();

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
        <GlobalStateProvider>
          <App />
        </GlobalStateProvider>
      </QueryClientProvider>
    </BrowserRouter>
    <ToastContainer
      position="top-right"
      autoClose={2000}
      closeOnClick
      pauseOnFocusLoss
      draggable
      pauseOnHover
      theme="dark"
    />
  </StrictMode>,
);
```

The applciation build should be successful